# The map from the decomposition group to the Galois group of the residue fields

Tags: algebraic-number-theory, fields, number-fields

$\DeclareMathOperator\Gal{Gal}$Let $L/K$ be a Galois field extension. Let $L$ be a **field** and $K$ be a **number field**. Let $B$ be a valuation subring of $L$ and let $A$ be the preimage of $B$ in $K$ (i.e the comap of $B$). Let $F_B$ and $F_A$ be the residue fields of $B$ and $A$ respectively. Let $D$ be the decomposition group and $\Gal(F_B /F_A)$ be the residual Galois group. Then the natural map $D \rightarrow \Gal(F_B /F_A)$ is surjective.

It is a standard result that in the case where $L$ and $K$ are both number fields, then the map is surjective.

But is the statement also true in the case where $K$ is a number field but $L$ is an arbitrary field? If it's true, what's the proof (or a reference with the proof)?

Comment: Do you mean $L$ is an infinite extension of $K$?

Comment: Right, that's actually the case I am interested in.

Comment: I think you can view $\mathrm{Gal}(L/K)$ as the inverse limit of Galois groups of finite extensions and then get the desired result. A well-known result is if we take $K$ as a local field then the map from $\mathrm{Gal}(\bar{K}/K)$ to that of its residue field is surjective.

Comment: Oh, sorry. The statement was wrong (I mentioned residue fields without mentioning the valuation subrings of $L$ and $K$) and I should have added that my main goal is to find the proof in the specific case where $K=\mathbb{Q}$ and $L=\bar{\mathbb{{Q}}}$ (but of course it would be great to know the proof in the general case).